# TIFF resolution decreases when opening it in the layout (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, layouts, resolution, png

I have a TIFF which I want to put in to the layout in order to add the legend etc. However, when I open it in the layout the resolution decreases significantly. I tried it with the TIFF as well as with a PNG. Its the same issue. I also played around with the setting such as DPI/other coordinate systems but didn't get better results. I also generated a pyramide file for better resolution when zooming in and out. But I don´t see a difference.

Comment: Do you have overviews in your tif? Maybe QGIS makes coarse result if it must downsample the image on-the-fly.

Comment: What resize mode did you use?

Comment: Do I have to resize the tif? I played around with the resizing but I didnt see a difference.

Comment: Raster image items added to map layouts often look really yucky in the preview, does it still look bad when you export the layout to pdf/image though?

Comment: Yes its the same bad quality when exporting the layout to a pdf.